# error: %preun(sdcss-kmod-10.0.2-1246.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Tags: linux, rhel, rhel7, symantec

I am trying to remove this package but gating error.

Aborting uninstall as Agent does not seem to be installed correctly.
File "/usr/lib/symantec/sdcssagent/lib/instfunlib-kmod" or "/etc/symantec/sis/rc.functions" is inaccessible, or is missing.
If protection is enabled, it must be disabled before uninstalling.
Otherwise, a manual uninstall must be performed to remove this software.
Refer to product documentation to perform a Manual Uninstall.

error: %preun(sdcss-kmod-10.0.2-1246.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error: sdcss-kmod-10.0.2-1246.el7.x86_64: erase failed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure that you have deleted below folders:

   rm -rf /opt/Symantec/sdcssagent/

   rm -rf /etc/sisips

   rm -rf /etc/symantec/sis/

   rm -rf /var/log/sdcsslog/

   rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/sdcss.repo
2. Once all are deleted, then run below command to clean up entry from rpm DB

   rpm -e --justdb sdcss

   rpm -e --justdb sdcss-kmod
3. Verify that packages are removed

   rpm -qa | grep sdcss